# Wamp basic configuration: "The requested URL /my-site/ was not found on this server."

Tags: wamp

I've just installed Wamp on a new computer with Windows 10 and I don't succeed to access any project in the "www" folder.

For example, I've created the folder "*C:\wamp64\www\my-site*" with a simple index.html file, but when I launch "[localhost/my-site/](http://localhost/my-site/)", I have the following error:

> ## **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /my-site/ was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> *Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at localhost Port 80*

On the other hand, "[localhost/](http://localhost/)" and "[localhost/phpmyadmin/](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/)" work perfectly fine.

I checked *httpd.conf* flie and everything seems to be okay:

```
#...
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
#...
ServerName localhost:80
#...
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/"
#...
```

Any idea to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just find what was my problem.

I didn't create a *index.html* but a *index.html.txt* ...

And what troubled me is that with Wamp 3, the error was a 404 error. With Wamp 2, when you don't have an index file (or a *.htaccess*), it shows you the folder content.

Comment: It seems the existence of a named page `index.html` on the root project location is mandatory to be launched on this server, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. phpmyadmin works well but access to the other project was not allowed. wamp server 3 does not allow access to the folder and the file listing. This folder must include at least one index.php or .htaccess
So if index.php is in the way www / myproject / folder1 / index.php. if you write localhost / myproject / the access will be denied. so you have to write localhost / myproject / folder1

Test create index.php in localhost/my-site/

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days trying everything I can read...nothing worked.

Then I looked at the database, wp_posts table and saw under the "guid" column that the URLs (www.example.com/?p=43) looked different from what the Permalinks looked like in Wordpress when you are in the Edit Page mode or when you want to "Preview" (www.example.com/2016/sample-posts/). That tipped me off.

So I went into the Wordpress dashboard >> Settings >> Permalinks, and changed the Permalink Setting to the format that matches the actual permalink format in wordpress.

Viola!

Hope this helps.

PS: make sure that your Apache httpd.conf file is set to allow mod-rewrite. Look for this line:

#### #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Simply get rid of the pound sign in front of it. So it looks like this:

**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

Answer (score 0):

Again WAMP configuration - a simple tool for simple people! Ehh. I post here after 1 hour searching and trying for reason why my permaliks don't work ...

Add to your HTACCESS file a simple cofig https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Add ...

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

to this config.

SUMMARY:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Options FollowSymLinks

# END WordPress
```

Boom!